# Makefile project in eclipse

Tags: eclipse

I am trying to build a project in eclipse with a Makefile I wrote and I get error:

```
make[1]: arm-linux-gcc: Command not found
```

But if I start eclipse from a Terminal, the same project is building ok

Any idea why this is happening?

My Makefile:

```
obj-m := file.o 

CROSS_COMPILE=arm-linux-
ARCH=arm 
KERNELDIR=/lib/modules/2.6.32.2/build
PWD       := $(shell pwd)

arm_modules:
    $(MAKE) -C $(KERNELDIR) M=$(PWD) LDDINC=$(PWD)/../include modules
    echo "bulding module for arm architecture:"


clean:
    rm -rf *.o *~ core .depend .*.cmd *.ko *.mod.c .tmp_versions

.PHONY: clean
```

Comment: It seems that your eclipse does not have the path for the `arm-linux-gcc` command, while when running from the terminal, it does recognize the command.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've fixed that problem by specifying my cross compiler's path in eclipse Tool Settings .